# How do you control individual slides in photos slideshow?

Tags: photos, slideshow

I am trying to make a simple slideshow with "ken burns" in Photos.  My problem is, when it transitions to video clips, the video is way too short, and not starting at the frame I would like it to.  How can I set the start point and duration of specific clip?  It's like photo slides are 4-5 seconds long as they are moving across the screen, and then my video clips are like only a second long...

Also, since I have a music track, I would like the video clips to not have their audio play.  How can I disable audio for a specific video clip in the slideshow?

Answer (score 1):

Different slideshow themes in Photos for Mac offer different options: See screenshot for (Left to Right) Origami, Ken Burns and Classic. Some themes let you specify 'Play Selected for X seconds', but only for still images - the check box is greyed out when a video is selected. The default Ken Burns settings also seems to play videos fleetingly. Classic theme plays complete videos. The audio in video clips can not be muted. Basically the slideshow functionality in Photos is quite basic. There are many dedicated slideshow apps on the Mac App Store, use one of those (I like Quik by Go Pro but there are plenty others.)

[image]